# What is the jTDS JDBC Connect URL to MS SQL Server 2005 Express

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2005, jdbc, jtds

I'm trying to connect to a MS SQL Server 2005 Express database that is running on the local host from a java program.

I have tried the same connect URL (below) that I used on another system (same jave code) that was running MS SQL Server 2000. But that does not work.

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/Finance
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Are you sure it is the correct instance? SQL Express tends to install as named instance, like "localhost\SQLExpress", instead of a standard instance. So it would be something like:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/Finance;instance=<instance_name>
```

If this doesn't work, try dropping the instance name, and changing the port to the port used by the named instance:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:<instance_port>/Finance
```

Else try to check your connectivity through OSQL.exe tool first. You can also check the [jTDS FAQ](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html) on this.

Comment: second option worked for me (if you specify host and port, should not be needed to specify instance....)

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest MicSim's url:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/Finance;instance=sqlexpress
```

Check [this](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat) for jTDS Url Info.

[This](http://softwaresalariman.blogspot.com/2007/04/jdbc-to-sql-server-express.html) also has some interesting information to help troubleshoot jtds to sql express sorts of problems.

Good luck.  Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is the first time I am working with SQLServer Express and I am finding it significantly different to SQLServer. I still cant connect properly, but it is now down to user permissions not the URL. I'll get back to it as soon as I get home (it is a home system I am working on).

Answer (score 0):

To check whether TCP/IP is enabled and the port is not blocked you can use "telnet  1433". Until telnet doesn't connect, jTDS won't either.

```
e.g, c:>telnet servername 1433
```

to enable telnet client on windows

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/910.how-to-enable-telnet-client-in-windows-7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Browser service is disabled by default. If you're developing .Net apps, you do not need to start SQLBrowser, but if you're using JTDS in Java, you will need to have it started.
Example (no need to specify the sql server port).

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/yourDbName;instance=SQLEXPRESS</property> 
<property name="connection.username">yourDbUser</property>
<property name="connection.password">yourDbPassword</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this::

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=Test1" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="vic123" />
</bean>
```