# how to write connection string (url) in eclipse for jtds to connect to Sql server 2008R2

Tags: java, eclipse, database-connection

I am new to eclipse.Can anybody help?
how to write connection string (url) in eclipse for jtds to connect to  Sql server 2008R2 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help me create a jTDS connection string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862283/help-me-create-a-jtds-connection-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=yourDB
```

duplicated a few other times :

[Help me create a jTDS connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862283/help-me-create-a-jtds-connection-string/1862508#1862508)

[What is the jTDS JDBC Connect URL to MS SQL Server 2005 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045958/what-is-the-jtds-jdbc-connect-url-to-ms-sql-server-2005-express/1046026#1046026)

Comment: I am new to eclipse.Can anybody help? how to write connection string (url) in eclipse for jtds to connect to Sql server 2008R2 ?

Server name- .(current)
Instance name-SQL2008ex
DBName- Sample
UserId-sa
Pwd-sa

Comment: can not connect to test Connection.Check Url.Network error IOException:Connection refused:connect.