# SQL Server Connection refused and jTDS driver not working

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I'm trying to connect to my local SQL Server Database. The database name is MDB and those are the credentials I use. Tried with `user="User"` as well and it didn't work.
I have the following jar into my library: `jtds-1.3.1.jar`
The version of SQL server I use is 2012.

```
String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1344/MDB;instance=sqlserver;useNTLMv2=true;";
String user = "User-PC\\User";
String pass = "";
```

I also tried with localhost:1099 and no success.

```
try
{
    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("1st error");
}
try
{
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( dbUrl, dbUser, dbPwd );
    System.out.println("Worked");
} catch (SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Driver error");
}
```

I have the JTDS jar into my external libraries.
The error I get is the following:

> java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused:
>   connect   at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.(JtdsConnection.java:436)
>     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)    at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)  at
>   Main.main(Main.java:33)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)  at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.createSocketForJDBC3(SharedSocket.java:288)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.(SharedSocket.java:251)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.(JtdsConnection.java:331)
>     ... 9 more

Info from SQL:
Login name:User-PC\User
Server name: USER-PC

Comment: Try port `1433`, I believe this is the default port.

Comment: check if your server is working or not

Comment: @SpringLearner, yes, I checked the config manager and tried even from db directly and it's up and running.

Comment: @hmjd, same error. Would it be possible to fix it with the microsoft version?

Comment: For both sqlexpress and mssqlserver... Maybe is a problem that I have both 2008 and 2010 versions?

Comment: @wero good ideea! Let me check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the jTDS JDBC Connect URL to MS SQL Server 2005 Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045958/what-is-the-jtds-jdbc-connect-url-to-ms-sql-server-2005-express)

Comment: @Filburt, I already tried that, saw the post before asking the question. It didn't solve my problem. 
Also, turned firewall off and it didn't fix anything.

Comment: @SimplyMe [Help me create a jTDS connection string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1862283/205233) also has more points to check (if you didn't already find it).

Comment: Checked the firewall (disabled). Checked the antivirus, checked the port, the jar, redownloaded it, restart sql server, recheck if it's active...

Comment: If you connect to an instance, you need to drop the port and make sure the SQL Server Browser service is running.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure TCP/IP ports are enabled in SQL server configuration and the SQL Server Browser service is also running.

Comment: How to make sure that?